# Use GRASS digitiser tools in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-7.0

I have QGIS with GRASS 7. I'm looking for the old style GRASS digitising tools.

- Previously, when digitising boundaries, it was required to split any adjacent boundaries intended to be joined to. The split tool seems to be missing in GRASS 7.

The toolset was also included in earlier versions of QGIS and the two (GRASS and QGIS) worked well together. I can't digitize even simple areas using current versions of GRASS and QGIS.

Comment: You could try using OSGeo4W to tailor your installation of QGIS and GRASS. See my answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254981/problem-with-qgis-installation-has-stopped-running-startup-after-new-installat/255055#255055

Comment: I'm curious : could you explain a bit more what "tools" you used ? It seems to me all the GRASS 6 tools (like v.split.* type tools) exist in GRASS 7. However, if you are editing vector entites within QGIS, why don't you use qgis editing tools ?

Comment: Hi, apologies for the late response.  To clarify some points in my original post:

Comment: To clarify some points in my original post: the tools I refer to are those button style tools that were grouped together on a 'GRASS Digitizer' toolbar in QGIS (also, if I remember correctly in GRASS standalone). I have access to all the module style tools (v.edit, v.clean etc). I've had a couple of days exploring the new QGIS/GRASS integration and have managed a workaround for my original problem, that of not being able to split boundaries when digitising so as to join in new boundaries to old ones in a way that was topologically correct.

Comment: Most of the old tools I refer to are now integrated into QGIS and become active when editing GRASS layers. My workaround is to use the 'add boundary' tool to digitise my new lines,  overlapping existing boundaries, saving, then running v.clean.break, then removing dangles left following the break.

Comment: Apologies for taking so long to respond: I'm running QGIS and GRASS on Mac OS - no OSgeo setup available for Mac as far as I know.

Comment: You seem to have created a second SE account. Please follow the directions [to merge your accounts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256689/how-to-merge-user-profiles)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/181956)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  You appear to have created two accounts which inevitably leads to a frustrating experience for you, potential answerers and reviewers so please follow [these instructions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) ASAP to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 1):

it seems strange you can't use digitizing tools, but i'll just answer your question concerning the use of old tools.

See @Martin Hügi comment and answer here  to be able to use the osgeo4W installer :
 [Problem with QGIS installation - Has stopped running startup after new installation?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254981/problem-with-qgis-installation-has-stopped-running-startup-after-new-installat/255055#255055).

When that is done, simply select the old tools in the setup like below bu clicking on "Skip" and make the version number appear :

[image: skip]

[image: Osgeo4W setup]

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to use the 'add boundary' tool to digitise new lines,  being sure to overlap existing boundaries. Once the edits are saved v.clean.break can be used to split boundaries at their overlaps. Finally, dangles left following the break can be removed one-by-one or by using a tool such as v.cleanrmdangles.